# Is there a Simple way to html decode several bound fields in formview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

Friends,
In my formview InsertTemplate we have several textboxes. When data is saved we run a loop to sanitize the data using a loop during ItemInserting:

```
Server.HtmlEncode(e.Values[a].ToString());
```

Thus, a value such as

```
<script> alert('Hello, World!') </script>
```

is converted and saved as

```
&lt;script&gt; alert('Hello, World!') &lt;/script&gt;
```

We show the same value to the user at the time of EDITTEMPLATE. This is is done by firing up the below code attached to each text box in EDITTEMPLATE.

```
 OnDataBinding="DecodeTextBox_DataBinding"
```

C# code:

```
((TextBox)sender).Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(((TextBox)sender).Text);
```

Upon doing this the EDITTEMPLATE textbox shows exactly what user has saved, which is:

```
 <script> alert('Hello, World!') </script>
```

The issue is that on and off we have to add additional text boxes per client's needs- there are too many such requests. Sometimes we forget to attach the databinding HtmlDecode to the new textboxes. 
Is there a way to run a loop on EDITTEMPLATE using HtmlDecode?

Comment: Why not just extend a textbox and override the Text getter/setter property?

Answer (score 0):

Although, I would look into doing a cleaner solution. The issue is that the textbox control encodes an already encoded HTML string. So, to decode them in bulk, you may try something like this.

Having a formview like this:

```
    <asp:FormView ID="myFormView" OnDataBound="myFormView_DataBound" DefaultMode="Edit" runat="server">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ItemA") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox2" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ItemB") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="TextBox1" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ItemA") %>'></asp:Literal>
            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="TextBox2" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ItemB") %>'></asp:Literal>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
```

You could recursively HtmlDecode all textboxes inside of it, after databinding has been executed:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var data = new[]{
            new DataObject(){
                ItemA = "&lt;div&gt;Item 1&lt;/div&gt;",
                ItemB = "&lt;div&gt;Item 2&lt;/div&gt;"
            }
        };

        myFormView.DataSource = data;
        myFormView.DataBind();


    }

    protected void myFormView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form = (FormView)sender;        
        HtmlDecode(form);
    }

    private void HtmlDecode(Control control)
    {
        if (control == null)
            return;

        foreach(var child in control.Controls.Cast<Control>())
            HtmlDecode(child);

        var textBox = control as TextBox;

        if (textBox == null)
            return;

        textBox.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(textBox.Text);
    }    
}

public class DataObject 
{
    public string ItemA { get; set; }
    public string ItemB { get; set; }
}
```